# Why not use 'took' but use 'takes' in the sentence of 'Big Ben takes its name from Sir Benjamin'?

Tags: grammar

The sentence:

> Big Ben **takes** its name from Sir Benjamin Hall who was responsible for the making of the clock when the new Houses of Parliament were being built.

In the sentence above, why not use **'took'**, but use **'takes'**? And we know that Big Ben was taken its name from Sir Benjamin Hall in the past.

Comment: Remember "Big Ben" is the bell, the clock tower was named "the Elizabeth tower"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentence, the first part is in present tense, as Big Ben is still a thing in the present, so 'takes' uses its present tense form.

'Took' on the other hand, is past tense, so would mainly be used if we were talking about an object that no longer exists.